# multiprocessing Pool hangs after finish

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-2.x

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool()` to split up a job, lets say using function `process()`

```
def process(data):
    #Process the data...
    print "Collecting data is finished!"
    return data

p=Pool(20)
output=p.map(process,range(2**30))
print "I am now processing the data"
```

I am noticing the time between when I get the message "Collecting data is finished" for the last job and when I get the message "I am now processing the data"  is pretty significant and seems to be dependent on the amount of a data being returned.  I am talking about maybe 10-20% of the total program time.

I see a similar pause if I use `imap()` as well.

I had assumed this is due to something like python pickling and unpickling the object that is returned. But then I tried using `map_async()` with a callback.

```
def writeFile(data):
   with open("file",'a') as f:
      for x in data:
         f.write(x)
   print "all Done"

res=p.map_async(process,data,callback=writeFile)
res.wait()
print "Program is done"
```

After this "all done" prints but `res.wait()` doesn't return for a long time.  I've had waits up to 5 additional minutes.  I have killed the process and confirmed nothing more was being written to the file, so now I am not sure it's due to data transfer between the child process and the parent.  Any suggestions for troubleshooting or speeding things up.

**EDIT**
I added another print statement to the end of the program, and it is printed after the callback print statement, but the program doesn't exit for several minutes... When I look at the processes, the main processes is the only one running, and it is running at 100% but no discernable work is being done...

**Test Script**

I wrote this test script.  I'm not sure how it will behave on other peoples computers.  I am running this on a pretty decent server with a ton of ram and 28 cores (you might want to remove the `mp.cpu_count()/2`, I do this to ignore hyperthreads).  The delay between finish and script continuation starts to become noticeable for me around 2^28 for the input.
I run out of ram at 2^30, but it still doesn't produce as pronounced of a pause as my data does.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

cpus=int(mp.cpu_count()/2)

def dothis(data):
    data= [x*x for x in data ]
    return data

def done(a):
    print "Im done",time.time()

def test():
    x=raw_input("2^:")
    bins=range(2**int(x))
    bins=[ bins[x:x+int(len(bins)/cpus)] for x in range(0,len(bins),int(len(bins)/cpus)) ]
    p=mp.Pool(cpus)
    r=p.map_async(dothis,bins,callback=done)
    p.close()
    r.wait()
    print "all done",time.time()

while True:
    print time.time()
    test()
```

**output**

```
2^:28
Im done 1601673676.28
all done 1601673676.28
1601673688.98

2^:29
Im done 1601674575.84
all done 1601674575.84
1601674599.24
```

Comment: Change `writeFile(()` to do nothing but print "all Done". If it's faster, could be due to all the disk I/O in that version.

Comment: A few key details are missing from your question. `1.` Your first example is missing `iterable` argument so it won't work. `2.` A note from the docs for your second example: `Callbacks should complete immediately since otherwise the thread which handles the results will get blocked.`. `3.` The most important, what is your data type for `data`? Btw do you still use Python 2...

Comment: This may also help - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @HTF I edited to put an iterable in the example.  I have checked and it's not the callback that is the issue.  The delay occurs even if nothing is done in the call back.  The data is a list of lists.   and as for python2... I am living in the 2010s, but when I'm developing I use it because I can work out a program without all the weird changes they made tripping me up (like int/int returning a float).  I'll get up to date someday...  I'm creating an example to run now